Is it possible to change the button image as a mouse event for the next button in NSIS?
(Using NSIS 3.10v, window 10, MUI2.nsh)
Is it possible to change the button image as a mouse event for the next button?
(I've tried using graphics-installer(1hour),
but I already have a lot of (UI) like modern.exe modified to ResourceHacker for customization,
so, if I use the above 'graphics-installer', I can't use 'Custom 'Contrib/UIs', so there's a limit to using graphics-installer.)

For example, I would like to do the following.

    System::Call 'user32::LoadImage(i 0, t "button.bmp", i ${IMAGE_BITMAP}, i 0, i 0, i ${LR_CREATEDIBSECTION}|${LR_LOADFROMFILE}) i.s'
    Pop $6
    SendMessage $NextButton ${BM_SETIMAGE} ${IMAGE_BITMAP} $6 


Or all leavepage functions (next events)
Should I use the method of changing the image?
The above example is only when you click the mouse, but it would be nice if there was a way to also change it in the mouse hover.

The next one worked for me.
https://nsis.sourceforge.io/SkinnedButton_plug-in

However, I am not sure if the link above applies to mouse hovering. The size of the example image file is three



It is definitely possible, you need to create new plugin or modify the https://nsis.sourceforge.io/SkinnedButton_plug-in.
SkinnedButton_plug-in currently works with 3 states: normal, focused (when there is Tab focus on control)  and clicked, so either add 4th state for mouse-over or change the logic for "focused".
StackOverflow is based on question-answer, probably no one will write the whole plug-in for you, but if you start writing that plug-in I will do my best to help you, I wrote several plugins for NSIS previously.
Also I checked the Graphical Installer changelog and they implemented this change some time ago:

So probably the fastest solution for you is to use just their .dll in your existing setup (of course get the Graphical Installer license first, it is a commercial software).
P.S. I was developer working on Graphical Installer

skinbutton doesn't seem to work based on nsis 3.10 unicode. If you check the value of the state that was popped after the skin init, an error occurs, and the error is just the name of the variable that was popped
but SkinControll.dll works fine

"Skinned Controls 1.4" version
I looked at the file 'SkinnedControls.c',
I was able to see the code of the message value for uMsg mouse click in the WndProc procedure section.
Should I define the mouse event behavior I want in this part?
I am currently using visual studio 2019(v142).
Which version of visual studio should I use
